# How to remove rows in a TableView javafx

Tags: java, javafx, initialization, tableview, javafx-8

I have been trying to add a remove button so that it removes a selected row in my tableview. My problem is slightly different from those i have found elsewhere. My problem lies behind the fact that in my application i have used 1 FXML file as the basis of several different interfaces. When i initialize 1 of these and use the functionality of the remove button it removes the tableView rows fine and how it is supposed to. But when i initialize a second interface (still using the same FXML and henceforth same variable names) it only lets me delete items in the 2nd tableView and not in the first. I have a good idea as to why this is, but i do not know how to fix it.

Here are a few methods i have tried:

```
public void removeProject(ActionEvent event){
int index = projectTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
  if(index >=0){
  projectTable.getItems().remove(index);
  }else
  //Show warning
  }
}
```

Another different approach:

```
public void removeProject(ActionEvent event){
ObservableList<Project> currentlySelected, allProjects;
currentlySelected = projectTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
allProjects = projectTable.getItems();
currentlySelected.forEach(allProjects::remove);
}
```

Also please keep in mind that both of these methods work fine until i initialize a second tableView. After this point the value i get from both my `ObservableList<Project> currentlySelected` and my `int Index`are -1 when i am trying to select a row in a table which isn't the most recent initialization of the interface. Sorry if it sounds a bit confusing but it is a bit confusing, if i can clear anything up ill add an edit later

Cheers

Edit 1:

Here is an example where i am trying to remove from the table based on which interface it is in currently:

```
ObservableList<Project> itemsSelected; 
        switch(counter){
        case 1:
            itemsSelected = projectTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
            itemsSelected.forEach(projTableStorage.getProj1()::remove);
            break;
        case 2:
            itemsSelected = projectTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
            itemsSelected.forEach(projectTableStorage.getProj2()::remove);
            break;
```

A few things to note:

1. The `projectTableStorage.getProj()` is used to store all of the data in each table, the returned value is an ObservableList and i use this to set the items of the table whenever that interface is loaded so the data is not lost when swapping between interfaces, perhaps there is more efficient ways to go about it, this is just how i did it
2. There are 7 of these interfaces, i am just testing with 2 to make testing shorter and simpler for now at least

Edit 2:

Loading FXML files:

```
public AnchorPane initLayouts(FXMLLoader loader, AnchorPane projectLayout, MainLayoutController mainLay) throws IOException{
    loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/control/view/ProjectLayout.fxml"));
    loader.setController(mainLay);
    projectLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
    return projectLayout;
}
```

in MainLayoutController:

```
public AnchorPane loadLayout(AnchorPane projectLayout, Project project, FXMLLoader loader)throws IOException{
    projectLayout = project.initLayouts(loader, projectLayout, this);
    return projectLayout;
}
```

load layout is called whenever a button is pressed

Edit 3:

Here is the 'removeProjec' code again

```
public void removeProject(ActionEvent event){
    ObservableList<Project> itemsSelected, currentProject; 
    itemsSelected = getProjectTable().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
    itemsSelected.forEach(getProjectTable().getItems()::remove);
    System.out.println("value of itemsSelected is : " + itemsSelected);
}
```

and my project table storage:

```
ObservableList<Project> project1= FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
ObservableList<Project> project2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 

public void setProject1(Project project){
    project1.add(project);
}

public void setProject2(Project project){
    project2.add(project);
}

public ObservableList<Project> getProject1(){
    return project1;
}
public ObservableList<Project> getProject2(){
    return project2;
}
```

And also just in case the getProjectTable method(Tried with and without annotation):

```
@FXML
public TableView<Project> getProjectTable(){
    return projectTable;
}
```

Edit 4:

```
public void createNewProjectLayout(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

    if(event.getTarget() == newProjectLayoutButton1){
        projectLayout1 = loadOrReloadProjectLayout(newProjectLayoutButton1, project1, projectLayout1, 1);
        setTable(Counter);

    }else if(event.getTarget() == newProjectLayoutButton2){
        projectLayout2 = loadOrReloadProjectLayout(newProjectLayoutButton2, project2, projectLayout2, 2);
        setTable(Counter);

    }
```

A few things to note:

The loadOrReload is simply to load the file the first time it is clicked using the loadLayout method previously mentioned, and then reload the result of loadLayout for the next time it is pressed

The `setTable` is used to set any data stored previously in the table to be put in the table again using the observable lists from the ProjectTableStorage class

Comment: Are the tableview and the remove button defined in fxml that you mentioned? Can you show the code where both loaded fxml files use the same variable name. I mean which variables are you talking about?

Comment: @UlukBiy I have added a code extract in edit 1, not sure if it helps but its there

Comment: Both in case 1 and 2, you are getting the selected items from the same tableview. Or is it just typo?

Comment: @UlukBiy That is my problem, as i said, i have made several interfaces based off the same FXML file, as far as my knowledge knows of javaFX at the moment, i can only make one FX : ID per item in an FXML file and since both case 1 and case two's interfaces are based off the same FXML then i have to use the same variable name. Can i perhaps reference the scene or parent of that interface(since they each have their own anchorpane as a parent when i initialize them), or maybe ill just have to make 7 FXML files with the exact same layout on each, which seems like a waste to me

Comment: Having a different parents for every loading is a right approach imo. Something like: AnchorPane pane1 = fxmlloader.load(); then later AnchorPane pane2 = fxmlloader.load(); etc.

Comment: I don't know where you placed the removal code you hve posted above in the question, but it is better to define delete action event in the controller of the fxml. So every loaded instance of the interface has its own isolated deletion code with its own loaded tableview items.

Comment: @UlukBiy Thats what i've done right now, but what do i do to go from there, how would i reference an individual table in reference to that anchorpane or parent rather? something like `pane1.projectTable` wouldn't work, so i'm lost on that part of it i guess

Comment: @UlukBiy The deletion code is in the controller, but the error is still there, i will try remove all the cases and just leave it as is

Comment: You can add a getter as fxmlControllerInstace.getProjectTable() which returns @FXML injected tableview. But why do you need this? Are you trying to access tableview from another controller? ...... Ok try it.

Comment: @UlukBiy I just tried to do the same thing without cases, and simply deleting the row when i click remove, but again the problem arises where whatever is selected in the 1st table(that is no longer the most recently initialized) i get a value of `[ ]` when using an ObservableList or a value of -1 when using the `selectedIndex()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79510/discussion-between-uluk-biy-and-provingbard).

Comment: @UlukBiy I tried using a `getProjectTable<Project>` method, and had both `return this.projectTable;` and also annotated the method with FXML when the previous approach didn't work. Even when i use this method i still get either `[]` or `-1`.